# How to get Class , method and line number of uncaught exception using NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, uncaught-exception

I used `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);` for handling uncaught exceptions in the method

```
void HandleExceptions(NSException *exception)
{
}
```

I want to print Class , method and line number where that exception occurred any solution??

I am getting Following stack trace

```
0   appName                            0x00000001000b6a20 HandleExceptions + 584
    1   appName                            0x00000001002175f0 GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler + 716
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001852fe95c <redacted> + 692
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000195a103b4 <redacted> + 116
    4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0000000195211bb4 <redacted> + 16
    5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x000000019521173c __cxa_rethrow + 144
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000195a10294 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001851e1154 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    8   GraphicsServices                    0x000000018e38b5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000189b163c0 UIApplicationMain + 1488
    10  appName                            0x00000001000a8584 main + 108
    11  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000019607ea08 <redacted> + 4
```

Comment: Print the stack trace

Comment: @Rohit_RK - have you found a solution for this? i am having a similar issue, no reasonable way to decode it yet.

Comment: @KarthikSadhasivam in the handle 'HandleExceptions(NSException *exception)'  method which is defined in **AppDelegate.m** you can get the instance of the NSException which we can use  to find exactly where the uncaught Exception occurred in our code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler gets an instance of [`NSException`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSException/callStackSymbols). There are two methods: `-callStackSymbols` and `-callStackReturnAddresses`.

`-callStackSymbols`gives you the backtrace strings, if it is possible.

It looks like this:

```
0   TestArrayCopy                       0x0000000100000dfe -[MyClass method] + 46
1   TestArrayCopy                       0x0000000100000e97 main + 87
2   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff940be5fd start + 1
3   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

As you can see, there is an information about the method owner (`-` for instance methods), the class name (`MyClass`) and the method name (`method`).

Comment: but callStackSymbols returns stack how to get exact Class , method and line number from it

Comment: Did you have a look to the strings? I added an explanation.

Comment: How I can decode the StackSymbols which I am getting??

Comment: With `NSString`, `NSScanner`, or $whatever.

Comment: can please check my question again I have added stack trace which I am getting

Comment: Well, that isn't inside a method. Something goes completely wrong there.

Comment: I printed this call stack in AppDelegate.m where I handled Uncaught exception

Comment: So, you have to check, what went wrong. Logs? BTW: For debugging you can simply set a exception break point. (It is an option, when setting a breakpoint.) You should have said that …

Comment: Line number? you missed it @AminNegm-Awad